# How to parse generic or any json to csv using python

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, data-conversion

I have few JSON files which needs to be parsed into CSV.

Below is my code :

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
def flatten_json1(y):
    out = defaultdict(list)
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], a )
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name )
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name].append(x)

    flatten(y)
    return out


import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('testjson.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

pprint(flatten_json1(data))
```

And this is a sample JSON I am using:

```
{
   "id": "0001",
   "type": "donut",
   "name": "Cake",
   "ppu": 0.55,
   "batters":
   {
      "batter":
      [
         { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
         { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
         { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
         { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
      ]
   },
   "topping":
   [
      { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
      { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
      { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
      { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
      { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
      { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
      { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
   ]
}
```

When run it provides me with below output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'type': [u'None', u'Glazed', u'Sugar', 
u'Powdered Sugar', u'Chocolate with Sprinkles', u'Chocolate', u'Maple', 
u'Regular', u'Chocolate', u'Blueberry', u"Devil's Food", u'donut'], 
u'id': [u'5001', u'5002', u'5005', u'5007', u'5006', u'5003', u'5004', 
u'1001', u'1002', u'1003', u'1004', u'0001'], u'ppu': [0.55], u'name': 
[u'Cake']})
```

But as you can see, the attribute "ppu" and "name" keys doesn't have the list size equal to the other 2 keys.

So, how can I make it possible like below:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'type': [u'None', u'Glazed', u'Sugar', 
u'Powdered Sugar', u'Chocolate with Sprinkles', u'Chocolate', u'Maple', 
u'Regular', u'Chocolate', u'Blueberry', u"Devil's Food", u'donut'], 
u'id': [u'5001', u'5002', u'5005', u'5007', u'5006', u'5003', u'5004', 
u'1001', u'1002', u'1003', u'1004', u'0001'], u'ppu': 
[0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55], u'name': [u'Cake’,u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake'u'Cake']})
```

Which is of length 12 each. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: below json fails with solution below:

{"build":"Jack","locID":"Jack1","active":false,"availableDate":"2018-24-11","ages":"123","hierID":["jack"],"locHier":[{"org":"jack1","active":true,"country":"IND1","availableDate":"2018-24-12","childNodes":[{"org":"jack2","active":true,"country":"IND2","availableDate":"2018-24-13","childNodes":[{"org":"jac3","active":true,"country":"IND3","availableDate":"2018-24-14","childNodes":[{"org":"jack4","active":false,"country":"IND4","availableDate":"2018-24-15","childNodes":[{"org":"jack5","active":true,"country":"IND5","availableDate":"2018-24-16"}]}]}]}]}]}

Comment: @ggorlen if we use the json above and convert to csv, will find for country as IND2 the active flag becomes "false",whereas in json its "true".

If we are able to solve this,it will awesome.
By flattening the json,the order gets distorted,if the same key is present outside the arrayList

Comment: [Try it] https://repl.it/repls/LittlePoliteLists

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the maximum length your longest array will be while building the flat dict result, you can loop over your result keys after you've constructed the result and pad each array with the last element.

In your second example, child nodes have new keys not present in the root which throws off the row alignment. I added a test for this to determine if the missing key is contained in the root; if it is, unshift a blank space to maintain alignment. Note that a more robust solution would be required if you have totally dynamic keys on all your items, but that appears premature.

```
def flatten_json(data):
    result = defaultdict(list)

    def flatten(x, name=""):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for k, v in x.items():
                flatten(v, k)
        elif type(x) is list:
            for v in x:
                flatten(v, name)
        else:
            result[name].append(x)

    flatten(data)
    max_length = max([len(v) for v in result.values()])

    for v in result.values():
        if max_length - len(v) == 1:
            v.insert(0, "")

        v.extend([v[-1]] * (max_length - len(v)))

    return result
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'id': ['0001', '1001', '1002', '1003', '1004', '5001', '5002',
                    '5005', '5007', '5006', '5003', '5004'],
             'name': ['Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake',
                      'Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Cake'],
             'ppu': [0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55,
                     0.55, 0.55],
             'type': ['donut', 'Regular', 'Chocolate', 'Blueberry',
                      "Devil's Food", 'None', 'Glazed', 'Sugar',
                      'Powdered Sugar', 'Chocolate with Sprinkles', 'Chocolate',
                      'Maple']})
```

and

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'active': [False, True, True, True, False, True],
             'ages': ['123', '123', '123', '123', '123', '123'],
             'availableDate': ['2018-24-11', '2018-24-12', '2018-24-13',
                               '2018-24-14', '2018-24-15', '2018-24-16'],
             'build': ['Jack12', 'Jack12', 'Jack12', 'Jack12', 'Jack12',
                       'Jack12'],
             'country': ['', 'IND1', 'IND2', 'IND3', 'IND4', 'IND5'],
             'hierID': ['jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack'],
             'locID': ['Jack123', 'Jack123', 'Jack123', 'Jack123', 'Jack123',
                       'Jack123'],
             'org': ['', 'jack1', 'jack2', 'jac3', 'jack4', 'jack5']})
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/FlippantPartialIntroductory)

Comment: if we use the json above and convert to csv, will find for country as IND2 the active flag becomes "false",whereas in json its "true". If we are able to solve this,it will awesome. By flattening the json,the order gets distorted,if the same key is present outside the arrayList.

which means the error is the index gets changed,when same keys are present

Try the link :
https://repl.it/repls/LittlePoliteLists

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what the problem is in your example. `IND2` is still `True` and all of the fields appear to line up. What output are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry my bad ,IND4 which is false, becomes true .
Similarly IND1/IND5 or any key,which should be present for 1 instance doesnt happen,rather it repeats itself. @ggorlen 

The output which i require ,when converted to csv looks like below image
[https://imgur.com/SdbSAOS] link to image

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: OK, the output you posted is totally different than what you requested in your question because a blank cell was inserted at the top of some rows. Does this mean you're left-padding rather than right padding each of your arrays? What is your logic for adding these spaces? Update your question with all of the information you've added in comments and explain how you're getting the result output, please.